# JWT invalid signature issue with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, jwt, express-jwt

I know this issue is common I have found several posts here and researched all over the internet but still no luck at all and I have spend half of the day.

Here is my NodeJS code:

```
jwt.sign(jwtData, config.secret, {
                    expiresIn: 60 * 60 * 24 // expires in 24 hours
                }, (err, token) => {
                    res.access_token = token
                    console.log("------------", res)
                    callback(null, res)
                })
```

---

```
jwt.verify(res.access_token, config.secret, function(err, decoded) {
                                if (err) {
                                   console.log("err----", err)
                                } else {
                                    cb({
                                        message: 'Token Exist'
                                    })
                                }
                            });
```

Error says : **JsonWebTokenError: invalid signature**

Also, I am able verify token on official site and it is working over there with valid signature.

I have checked my secret whether it is a string or not and it is a string.

Thanks in advance!!!

EDIT:

```
res.access_token--- eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MjUsInJvbGVfaWQiOjIsImlzX3BheW1lbnRfZmFpbCI6MCwiaXNfcGFpZCI6MSwiaXNfb3duZXIiOjEsImZpcnN0X25hbWUiOiJTYWdhciIsImxhc3RfbmFtZSI6IlZpcnBhcmEiLCJpYXQiOjE1ODMzMjU4NDYsImV4cCI6MTU4MzQxMjI0Nn0.8LNFXPwSPjjbZE9IWh0p7Xri8t

config.secret----- #&%S0l!dP1vE*@!%
```

Comment: Are you sure config.secret is the same for sign and verify?  You can console.log and compare.

Comment: and also show the `console.log` of `res.access_token`

Comment: @SuleymanSah yeah I was bit worries about that but I have cheked that and it is coming from the config file and has same type

Comment: @jps Please check edited post

Comment: with that secret signature verification fails on jwt.io

Comment: @jps Mine is valid please at your end

Comment: No, it's really not valid! Please **first** paste the secret to the field on the right column, **then** paste the token to the field on the left. Then it fails. When you do it the other way arround (I assume you did), then jwt.io recalculates the hash and modifies the signature on your token and then tells you "signature verified", which means the changed signature is valid.

Comment: @jps Okay that's good. So what do I need to do ?

Comment: The code looks ok (though I didn't try it), so either the token or the key changed between sign and verify. Only you know the whole code and can debug to see what happens.

Comment: @jps I have debuged code and console log both sign verify before after but still getting the same output with the same before after o/p.

Comment: the token you have shown is truncated, there are exactly 17 characters missing on the end. The real token is `eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6MjUsInJvbGVfaWQiOjIsImlzX3BheW1lbnRfZmFpbCI6MCwiaXNfcGFpZCI6MSwiaXNfb3duZXIiOjEsImZpcnN0X25hbWUiOiJTYWdhciIsImxhc3RfbmFtZSI6IlZpcnBhcmEiLCJpYXQiOjE1ODMzMjU4NDYsImV4cCI6MTU4MzQxMjI0Nn0.8LNFXPwSPjjbZE9IWh0p7Xri8tbnNzRBElmn_0hhM0k` . Is this your mistake when you pasted the token here or is the token in your code exactly what you got in the variable `res.access_token`?

Comment: @jps Ohh... I really appreciate your answer.. Problem was a limit of datatype in mysql...

Comment: Glad to hear it's solved now, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that I was storing the token in `varchar(255)` data type and a token were trimming automatically due to limitation of the datatype.

So, I have just changed data type to text and it was working perfectly.

Thanks to @jps